# Edit catalina.sh in Openshift v3 Tomcat Image

Tags: tomcat, openshift, openshift-3

I am using Tomcat 8 Image in Openshift v3 and have deployed a java app using github repo.

Now I want to edit the `catalina.sh` file to add additional VM arguments when the server starts.

Can someone please tell me/point me how I can edit the `catalina.sh` file so that I can add the additional vm args to the `JAVA_OPTS` variable.

The closest answer which I could get was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45309043/1848326) but this talks about building your own tomcat image which I do not want as I am using the image from openshift catalog.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the JAVA_OPTS or CATALINA_OPTS using `oc set env` command in the tomcat pod.[0]

FYI [1][2], I also hope to take inspiration for your solutions by referring the usage of jvm parameters in the docker containers.

[0] [ https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/environment_variables.html#set-environment-variables ]

[1] [ https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/issues/8 ]

[2] [ https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/202 ]