# Dockerfile error, "<filename> not found" on run docker

Tags: docker

I found the following discussion re: getting a

["executable file not found in $PATH"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158840/docker-executable-file-not-found-in-path)

That solved my problem, but only partially.  On my last command I
am specifying:

`CMD /home/ubuntu/node-v0.10.16-linux-x64/bin/node launch.js`

The image builds without any errors or warnings.  However, when I
docker run `<image>`, I am now getting the following error:

> /bin/sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/node-v0.10.16-linux-x64/bin/node: not found

That directory is included in my `ENV PATH` statement.  What else do I
need to look for?

Comment: By editing my question so severely you altered the context I was setting to ask it.  I wish you wouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

> That directory is included in my ENV PATH statement

That doesn't seem to be relevant, since you are providing the full path of the command.
It should simply mean that full path does not exist in the running container.

In order to check that:

- remove your CMD in your `Dockerfile`
- build and run your container
- open a bash in your running container (unless the default docker run opens a bash session)

That is:

```
docker exec -it <yourContainer> bash
ls /home/ubuntu/node-v0.10.16-linux-x64/bin/node
```

Or:

```
docker run -it --rm <yourContainer> bash
which node
```

It should be in `/usr/sbin/node`.
Since `/usr/sbin/` is in the `root` account's `$PATH`, the `CMD` can simply be:

```
CMD [ "node", "/path/to/your/launch.js" ]
```

Comment: Running  docker exec -it <containerName) bash yields the error: Error response from daemon: no such id: <containerName>.   (Oh, and before that, docker run  <containerName> didn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: @tlwtheq what is your `Dockerfile`? What is its base image (`FROM` directive)? Note that `docker run` would use `<imagename>`, not `<containername>`: `docker run --name <containername> <imagename>`: run a container named `<containername>` from the image named `<imagename>`.

Comment: FROM ubuntu:12.04
 My container name and my image name are the same.

Comment: @tlwtheq in your Dockerfile, did you change the  `ENTRYPOINT`? In order to have a running container, you should do a `docker run -it --rm --name <containername> <imagename> bash`: that would open a container with a bash (instead of the default `CMD`, which does not execute anyway). Once in the bash, you can explore the container and see if the folder is there.

Comment: Interesting.  I just did a modified version of what you suggested.  I.e.,           docker run -it <container|image name>.  This lands me in /, as username root.  The ID root certainly cannot see any version of "node", although an 'echo $PATH' has my container's path in it.  As I am famous for saying, "Now what?"  Oh, and I am in bash according to 'echo $SHELL'.

Comment: Also forgot to mention I just plain copied the "node" executable into my container's directory before the docked build.  No difference.

Comment: Oh, another thing.  When I land in the root directory, the docker executable isn't visible either.  "bash: docker: command not found"

Comment: @tlwtheq the id root is the default one: you can change the user with a `docker run -u anotheruser`

Comment: @tlwtheq "I just plain copied the "node" executable into my container's directory ": do you mean you have a `COPY` directive in your Dockerfile? If not, how exactly (what did you type) did you copy anything in your container *before* a docker build? You `docker build` first (an image), then you run a container (from that built image)

Comment: I mean I literally copied the node tool, cp node, into the directory where I am performing the build, then did the build.

Comment: When I specified my username the System couldn't find it.  Error response from daemon: Cannot start container ebd9f7eb6c99968b3067bd384009e9ae8c10706fb424368745c217c8b246d0f5: [8] System error: Unable to find user ubuntu

Comment: @tlwtheq that copy would have any effect if you then have on the Dockerfile used by docker build a `COPY node /somewhere` directive.

Comment: @tlwtheq I agree that specifying your host username is unknown in a container environment. Why root is a problem here?

Comment: I don't understand the sentence: "that copy would have any effect if you then have on the Dockerfile used by docker build a COPY node /somewhere directive."  The root ID cannot see my launch command, or the node executable.

Comment: @tlwtheq the root id can see anything present in the container: it has full access. Regarding the copy, copying anything in the host has no effect on the resulting image, unless your Dockerfile COPY it (see https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#copy)

Comment: I think my Dockerfile is not right, in more ways than one, but don't want to post it.  Is there some way I can email it to you?

Comment: @tlwtheq sure, but an interactive session would be more effective. I cannot create a chat room (you have not yet enough rep: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat), so look me up in Google Hangout (https://plus.google.com/u/0/+DanVonC1)

Comment: OK...got your picture up.  Now what?