# Setting $PATH in docker image?

Tags: bash, docker

I'm creating a base image for my projects. In this base image, I will download a few .tar.gzs and extract them.

I want to add these unzipped directories to be added to the path, so in child images, I can call up the downloaded executables directly without needing to specify the full path.

I tried running `export PATH...` in the base image, but that doesn't seem to work (at least when i tty into it, i don't see the path updated, I assume because the export doesn't transfer over into the new bash session).

Any other way to do this? Should I edit the .bashrc?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set some environment variables you can use the `-e` option to set environment variables. for example suppose you can do

`docker run -e PASSWORD=Cookies -it <image name> bash`

which when run you can check to see if `$PASSWORD` exists with an `echo $PASSWORD`

Comment: I want to set the path in the Dockerfile of the original image, so I can just run the children and they will have inherited the path from parent and I will not have to specify it myself each time

Answer (score 0):

Currently the way you are setting $PATH will not cause the modification to be persistent across sessions. Please see the Bash manual on [startup files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) to see which files you can edit to set the environment permanently,

Comment: What's the way to do it so it will persist?

Comment: In your Dockerfile, try omitting the square brackets from the command specified for the executable, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158840/docker-executable-file-not-found-in-path

Comment: Thanks, this works as a workaround, but this will probably have issues, e.g if my program crashes, it will probably exit to bash, and docker won't know that the program has crashed