# What is the reason for various "executable file not found in $PATH" errors?

Tags: docker

I have just started getting the following kind of errors with various images:

```
docker run -it elasticsearch

> error: exec: "elasticsearch": executable file not found in $PATH

docker run -it kibana

> error: exec: "tini": executable file not found in $PATH
```

If I run the exact same commands from a different host they work fine, with the same exact image. So I am led to believe that there is a problem on this particular host and not the images themselves

I have even rolled back to versions of the images used at a time when it worked and still get the same error. I have no idea why these errors have started happening.

Comment: Please see if this is helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158840/docker-executable-file-not-found-in-path

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't explain why it works on one host and not the other.

Comment: Is the image that you used available public to test? or do you want do a  clean test?

Comment: Are you sure `docker` is doing what you think on that host?

Comment: @Henry - what do you mean?

Comment: @Rao - yes it is the latest official elasticsearch image

Comment: @user3231690 I mean, is it really docker you are running or is the command doing something else?

Comment: did the first command, and working fine.

Comment: @Rao - yes, thanks for confirming. It is working on other hosts too. And did work fine on the 'broken' host.

Comment: @Henry - yes, it is just the regular docker command.

Comment: @user3231690, may be it would be more simple to clean the images in your system and re-run.

Comment: @Rao just did that, it still fails. Is it possible that these images were built against docker 1.12.2 and my host is 1.12.1 ?

Comment: In that case, you might consider upgrading your docker and give it a try.