# File not being bind mounted to docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running a `docker-compose` test; part of my stack that will perform the actual tests is the following service

```
  tester:
    image: tutum/curl:latest
    volumes:
      - ./ci/wait-for-it.sh:/usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh
      - ./webhooks:/app/webhooks
    depends_on:
      - sut
    command: ["wait-for-it.sh", "sut:8080", "-t", "240", "--", "sh", "pytest /app/webhooks"]
```

The command fails as follows:

```
ERROR: for 0114c9206690_alerta-_tester_1  Cannot start service tester: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"wait-for-it.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

ERROR: for tester  Cannot start service tester: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"wait-for-it.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

The file being mounted does exist:

```
▶ ls docker-compose.test.yaml
docker-compose.test.yaml

Workspace/systems-utils/  alerta_dev_infra ✗                                                                         1d ⚑ ◒
▶ ls ./ci/wait-for-it.sh
./ci/wait-for-it.sh
```

What is more, when trying to bind mount a non-existent file, instead of getting a mount-related error, i get the same error as above

```
  tester:
    image: tutum/curl:latest
    volumes:
      - ./ci/foofile.sh:/usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh
      - ./webhooks:/app/webhooks
    depends_on:
      - sut
    command: ["wait-for-it.sh", "sut:8080", "-t", "240", "--", "sh", "pytest /app/webhooks"]
```

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yaml up -d

ERROR: for tester  Cannot start service tester: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"wait-for-it.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

What am I missing?

**edit**: Regarding the `PATH` issue mentioned, here it is:

```
▶ docker run -it tutum/curl:latest printenv
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=1f3090676fa0
TERM=xterm
HOME=/
```

What is more, the `tester` service configuration is the exact same as in [this](https://github.com/alerta/docker-alerta/blob/master/docker-compose.test.yml#L24) project which runs perfectly.

As for the permissions issue:

```
Workspace/systems-utils/alerta-workable  alerta_dev_infra ✗                                                                        1d ⚑ ◒  ⍉
▶ ls -al ./ci/wait-for-it.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pkaramol  staff   5.1K Sep  6 22:02 ./ci/wait-for-it.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory - `wait-for-it.sh` is not on $PATH.

You need either add `/usr/local/bin` to $PATH or change command to

```
command: ["/usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh", "sut:8080", "-t", "240", "--", "sh", "pytest /app/webhooks"]
```

See also accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158840/docker-executable-file-not-found-in-path) for why `/usr/local/bin` might not be in path.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could not find "**executable** file in $PATH"

So let's try to set executable permissions on `./ci/wait-for-it.sh` file:

```
$ chmod +x ./ci/wait-for-it.sh
```

Comment: I have changed the file's permssions, but still the same error comes up

Comment: @pkaramol could you update docker-compose file to show which version it is?