# Not able to access file shared with init container

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am creating a file in init container and wanted to consume this file in main container.

```
  containers:
  - name: test1
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    image: newbusybox
    command:
    - "some command  --from-file=tmp/file.txt"
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir
      mountPath: /tmp
  initContainers:
  - name: install
    image: busybox
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args: ["echo test  > /pod-data/file.txt]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir
      mountPath: /pod-data/
  volumes:
  - name: workdir
    emptyDir: {}
```

Pods goes into crashlookBack off with following error

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"some command  --from-file=tmp/file.txt\": stat some comamnd  --from-file=tmp/file.txt: no such file or directory": unknown
```

I have verified file is mounted at tmp location.

Comment: Can you try to change the `command` fields to work like this? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#run-a-command-in-a-shell The error message indicates that the error is not in the file sharing, and rather in the command specification

Comment: I think your just missing a forward slash at the start (`--from-file=/tmp/file.txt` instead of `--from-file=tmp/file.txt`)

Comment: Ok I tried that too.  Same issue with ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

image: "ubuntu:14.04"
    command:
    - touch tmp.txt

---------------------------------------------------------------


Error: failed to start container "my-container": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"touch tmp.txt\": executable file not found in $PATH":

Comment: Please try to use in initContainer -> `command: ["bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "echo hello > /pod-data/hello.txt"]` . And in the main container:     `command: [/bin/sh]
    args: ["-c","cat /tmp/hello.txt; sleep infinity"]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish but I need to agree with a comment provided by user @Lauri Koskela:

> Can you try to change the command fields to work like this? [kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/…](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#run-a-command-in-a-shell) The error message indicates that the error is not in the file sharing, and rather in the command specification

The link that @Lauri Koskela posted:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Inject data application: Run a command in a shell](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#run-a-command-in-a-shell)*

Could shed some light on ways to parse the commands into the `Pods`.

> Also you have a typo in:
>
> - `args: ["echo test  > /pod-data/file.txt]`
> - `args: ["echo test  > /pod-data/file.txt"]` # <-- missing closing (")

---

```sh
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"some command  --from-file=tmp/file.txt\": stat some comamnd  --from-file=tmp/file.txt: no such file or directory": unknown
```

Error above is connected with the fact that you tried to run a command without specifying a shell (it's also connected with a comment you made). You can read more about it here:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: Docker: executable file not found in $PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27615958/12257134)*

If you were to:

```yaml
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"] 
    args: 
    - "some command  --from-file=/tmp/file.txt"
```

You should be able to run `some command`

Following this path, here is additional example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox-pod
  labels:
    app: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    image: busybox
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args: 
    - "cat /tmp/file.txt > /working.txt && sleep 3600"
    # - "cat /tmp/file.txt > /working.txt; sleep 3600"
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir
      mountPath: /tmp
  initContainers:
  - name: install
    image: busybox
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args: ["echo test > /pod-data/file.txt"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir
      mountPath: /pod-data/
  volumes:
  - name: workdir
    emptyDir: {}
```

This example will:

- Run an `initContainer` with `busybox` image and will save "test" text to a file named `file.txt` in `/pod-data/` directory
- Run main `container` and will `cat` the content of earlier created file now being in `/tmp` to a `working.txt` file. It will also sleep for 3600 seconds.

After running this container you can check if the file was read correctly by:

- `$ kubectl exec -t busybox-pod -- cat /working.txt`

```sh
hello
```