# How do you create a docker container automatically with a git download and automatic start with python?

Tags: python-3.x, git, docker

**Hey**
I try to automatical creat a docker container with this code

```
    clone = 'git clone ' + link
    print(clone)
    run = 'python3 ' + dateiname
    print(run)
    dockers = docker.from_env()
    userdocker = dockers.containers.run(
        image='python:3-alpine', stdout=True, name=author_name, command=[clone, run])
    log = userdocker.logs()
    print(log)
```

but I aslo get this error
*Internal Server Error ("OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "git clone ": stat git clone : no such file or directory: unknown")*

Is ther any way to fix this or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git` is not installed in the container. `git` It should be installed with `apk add git` before it can be used.

Try to build new container with `git` based on the `python:3-alpine`.

Create Dockerfile as follows

```
FROM python:3-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add git
```

Build the image

```
docker build -t mypython:3-alpine .
```

Then use this image instead of `python:3-alpine`.

Comment: Should I add it as a command as it doesn't work or by some other way I couldn't find

Comment: before executing the `git clone`. Either create new image that includes the `git` or add it before calling `git clone` as by example `clone = 'apk update && apk add git && git clone ' + link`

Answer (score 0):

I found also aut that I shouldn't use [] for a command here a  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158840/docker-executable-file-not-found-in-path) for more info