# How to attach a volume to a Docker container running Ubuntu on Mac?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am running a docker container with Ubuntu Xenial image on my macOS Big Sur using the command `sudo docker run -it ubuntu:xenial` and it works fine, giving me a Linux terminal.

However, I want to attach a volume to my container so that I can save the work that I do within the ubuntu terminal that I get from within the container on my Mac's filesystem. For that, I tried to run the following command:

`sudo docker run -it ubuntu:xenial -v /Users/myname/Documents/UbuntuWorkspace`

(I had previously created the directory named `UbuntuWorkspace`)

But I encountered the following error when I tried to run the above command:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "-v": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

So, what is the right way to attach a directory on my Mac's filesystem to the Ubuntu docker container that I run, so that I can save my work and also view it on the finder app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add the path to the dir in container and maybe you should use image name [after all arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34503625/16789286)

```
sudo docker run -it -v /Users/myname/Documents/UbuntuWorkspace:/some/path ubuntu:xenial
```

[Docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)