# starting container process caused: exec: "air": executable file not found

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, air

I am new to docker. I am trying to containerise my Go application using docker-compose.
Technology used
Golang, Docker 20.10.8 and Air (for live reloading).
My Dockerfile looks like this.

```
FROM base as dev


WORKDIR /opt/app/api

RUN apk update
RUN apk add git gcc musl-dev
RUN apk add curl

RUN curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosmtrek/air/master/install.sh | sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin

# RUN go get
# RUN go mod tidy

CMD ["air"]
```

My docker-compose.yml is this.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.local
      context: .
      target: dev
    container_name: 'server'
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/app/api
    env_file:
      - .env      
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart:
      always    
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
  
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    container_name: 'postgres'
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
        - rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
        - rabbitmq-log:/var/log/rabbitmq
  
  migrate: &basemigrate
    profiles: ["tools"]
    image: migrate/migrate
    entrypoint: "migrate -database postgresql://thursday:postgres@db/postgres?sslmode=disable -path /tmp/migrations"
    command: up
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
    - ./migrations:/tmp/migrations
  
  create-migration:
    <<: *basemigrate
    entrypoint: migrate create -dir /tmp/migrations -ext sql
    command: ""
    depends_on:
      - db
  
  down-migration:
    <<: *basemigrate
    entrypoint: migrate -database postgresql://thursday:postgres@db/postgres?sslmode=disable -path /tmp/migrations
    command: down
    depends_on:
      - db
          
volumes: 
  data:
  rabbitmq:
  rabbitmq-log:
```

On running command *sudo docker-compose up -d* I am getting the following error

Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "air": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Comment: The error is pretty clear `executable file not found`.

Comment: What does the `base` image look like? What is the `GOPATH` environment variable set to?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in "[docker: executable file not found in `$PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27615958/6309)":

When you use the exec format for a command (in your case: `CMD ["air"]`, a JSON array with double quotes) it will be executed without a shell.
This means that most environment variables will not be present.

`CMD air` should work, provided:

- `air` is an executable (`chmod 755`)
- `air` was cross-compiled to Linux (unless your host running docker is already Linux)