# COPY web server command to image but not found when run container

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I follow [Using the BusyBox Docker Image for Building Applications : A Complete Guide](https://www.sohamkamani.com/docker/busybox-guide/) to customize an image.

Using code [docker-busybox-example](https://github.com/sohamkamani/docker-busybox-example).

**Dockerfile**

```
# Use busybox as the base image
FROM busybox
# Copy over the executable file
COPY ./server /home/server
# Run the executable file
CMD /home/server
```

**web server**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World!")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    fmt.Println("Server running...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

compile as executable file `server` with `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build server.go`

**built image based busybox**

```bash
[mymachine@localhost tmp]$ docker image build -t go-server . 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.562MB                                                          
Step 1/3 : FROM busybox                                                                                  
 ---> beae173ccac6                                                                                       
Step 2/3 : COPY ./server /home/server                                                                    
 ---> Using cache                                                                                        
 ---> 9d58653768ea                                                                                       
Step 3/3 : CMD /home/server                                                                              
 ---> Running in 994cce171c11                                                                            
Removing intermediate container 994cce171c11                                                             
 ---> 38996797b6d8                                                                                       
Successfully built 38996797b6d8                                                                          
Successfully tagged go-server:latest
```

**when run the container, `server` is not found.I* I have no clues about this.

```bash
[mymachine@localhost tmp]$ docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm -it go-server ls -l /home                             
total 6408                                                                                               
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root       6559402 Oct 13 19:53 server                                          
[mymachine@localhost tmp]$ docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm -it go-server                                         
/bin/sh: /home/server: not found
```

but it works for this application

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

Does it not support web server executable file?

[docker: executable file not found in $PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158840/docker-executable-file-not-found-in-path) is not helpful

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `server` is a dynamic executable...

```
$ ldd server
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcbdbd2000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3a78527000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3a78325000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3a78554000)
```

...and the `busybox` image doesn't have any of the required runtime libraries. One solution is to use something other than busybox, e.g:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
COPY ./server /home/server
CMD ["/home/server"]
```

(I've modified your `CMD` statement here so that it's possible to kill the container using `CTRL-C`.)

The other option is to build a static executable:

```
$ CGO_ENABLED=0 go build
$ ldd server
        not a dynamic executable
```

This works fine with your original Dockerfile.