# Why are containers created on different hosts with the same version of Docker image, one with ls command and the other without it?

Tags: docker, nginx

Why are containers created on different hosts with the same version of Docker image, one with ls command and the other without it.  [the question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xxxN.png)

### i search almost document, does not found the answer, i want to know the reason of this, cause the situation?

machine A's output

```bash
docker run -it --name nginx --entrypoint ls nginx:1.25.1 /etc
adduser.conf            fonts      ld.so.cache    passwd       shadow
alternatives            fstab      ld.so.conf     passwd-      shadow-
apt                     gai.conf   ld.so.conf.d   profile      shells
bash.bashrc             group      libaudit.conf  profile.d    skel
bindresvport.blacklist  group-     localtime      rc0.d        ssl
ca-certificates         gshadow    login.defs     rc1.d        subgid
ca-certificates.conf    gshadow-   logrotate.d    rc2.d        subuid
cron.d                  gss        mke2fs.conf    rc3.d        systemd
cron.daily              host.conf  motd           rc4.d        terminfo
debconf.conf            hostname   mtab           rc5.d        timezone
debian_version          hosts      nginx          rc6.d        update-motd.d
default                 init.d     nsswitch.conf  rcS.d        xattr.conf
deluser.conf            inputrc    opt            resolv.conf
dpkg                    issue      os-release     rmt
e2scrub.conf            issue.net  pam.conf       security
environment             kernel     pam.d          selinux
```

machine B's output

```bash
docker run -it --name nginx --entrypoint ls  nginx:1.25.1 /etc     
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"ls\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

machine A's info

```bash
uname -a
Linux ubuntu2204.localdomain 5.15.0-69-generic #76-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 17 17:19:29 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.10.4)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.17.2)

Server:
 Containers: 2
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 2
 Server Version: 20.10.24
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc io.containerd.runc.v2
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 2806fc1057397dbaeefbea0e4e17bddfbd388f38
 runc version:
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.15.0-69-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu Core 22
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 7.763GiB
 Name: ubuntu2204.localdomain
 ID: C75T:TAOG:RQZP:LIYO:3MRE:W5ER:5I2D:IMUC:PTQP:LWZL:62KP:U5XQ
 Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Registry Mirrors:
  https://xxx
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

machine B's info

```bash
uname -a
Linux master 3.10.0-1160.an7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 14 16:04:36 CST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 145
  Running: 76
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 69
 Images: 252
 Server Version: 19.03.13
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: xfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: ea765aba0d05254012b0b9e595e995c09186427f
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1160.an7.x86_64
 Operating System: Anolis OS 7.9
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 6
 Total Memory: 11.58GiB
 Name: master
 ID: TMQB:QWTV:CQMU:FN32:TUU4:XQBZ:I4F3:DMX2:U4BV:MRU3:5JU6:YJHR
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http://172.31.1.1:8070
 HTTPS Proxy: http://172.31.1.1:8070
 No Proxy: 127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.0.0.0/8,192.168.0.0/16,169.254.0.0/16,100.0.0.0/8,168.0.0.0/8,localhost,svc,local
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Registry Mirrors:
  https://xxx
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Do not use images for that. Please use a proper formatting with backticks ```

Comment: @Moti Ok, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The versions of Docker on your machine A (`v20.10.24`) and machine B (`v19.03.13`) are different, so they are most likely reading the `docker run` command differently. Based on the information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34503625/10141530), you need to rearrange the command options on machine B.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem, so I'll change the command to: `docker run-it --name nginx --entrypoint ls nginx:1.25.1`, I query the run command of docker 19 and docker 20, the order of this command should be the same, However, ls command is still not found

Comment: Docker is designed so that containers created from an image work the same no matter what host they run on, so since you are using the same image to create both containers, there should be no difference between these, so the only scenario that makes sense is that the different versions of Docker on your machines are reading the command differently. Additionally, hundreds of people (as evidenced in the answer I linked) have had the same problem as you, so it seems to me that it makes sense to try running the command in multiple ways, until hopefully one works.

Comment: For example, I would try removing the `--name nginx` part and go from there to test variants. I have no way to test for you because the version of Docker on machine B is a bit old. If you tried many variants and none worked, as a last measure I would try reinstalling or upgrading Docker on machine B (very carefully, because you have a lot of containers running there).

Comment: To eliminate the effect of the command, I changed the command to `docker run -d nginx:1.25.1` and then ran it on two servers and went into their respective containers to execute ls. Here is the result:

Comment: machine A's output:
```shell
root@ubuntu2204:~# docker run -d nginx:1.25.1
ac3fc10509d4cd34f79e72e224c8ec64471e667860bb32b25e791fd9a0aebf1a
root@ubuntu2204:~# docker exec -it ac bash
root@ac3fc10509d4:/# ls
bin   dev                  docker-entrypoint.sh  home  lib32  libx32  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  docker-entrypoint.d  etc                   lib   lib64  media   opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
root@ac3fc10509d4:/#
```

Comment: machine B's output:
```shell
[root@master ~]# docker run -d  nginx:1.25.1     
a98e9d348aa3724a26e1952880d2314d89de12b2d6418642aa1302b35d3b96cc
[root@master ~]# docker exec -it a98 bash
root@a98e9d348aa3:/# ls
bash: ls: command not found
root@a98e9d348aa3:/#
```